# Writing panels/docks with pyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, openbox

I want to write something like a taskbar/dock/panel(like tint2,...) with pyQt5.

I know how to write regular GUI applications with it, but my tiling window manager(herbstluftwm) maximizes my panels and openbox makes them resizable etc.
My question : How can I make pyQt show my application as a panel instead of a window? I haven't found anything about that in the documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify how you differentiate between "panel" and "window"? Do you need to prevent the automatic resizing of windows *from* the window manager?

Comment: I want my application to be not resizable, not movable, popping up at a specific location(with a specific size) on the screen, not showing close/maximize/minimize-buttons and not hidden below other windows.

Comment: I don't have a tiling window manager right now to test it, but, have you already tried to use `setFixedSize()`?

Comment: It doesn't work. Seems like tiling window managers ignore these commands. But Other panel apps, for example tint2, work.

Comment: But the size is set correctly in floating mode.

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried to use `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.ToolTip)`?

Comment: Thanks. setWindowFlags() is the function I've been searching for.

Comment: Then I suggest you to answer your own question by providing the explanation and a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing how you solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to musicamente's help, i could find that the function setWindowFlags() is what I need. It allows to change the behavior of a window.

A website explaining this function is https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-window-flags/